# Chrome Extension CSS File - Stalled

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My extension css file is getting stalled and I can't understand why

[image]

I am loading it inside the head of an iframe the extension injects into the page:

```
const head = (
  <>
    <link
      href={browser.extension.getURL("/css/content.css")}
      rel="preload"
      as="style"
    ></link>
    <link
      href={browser.extension.getURL("/css/content.css")}
      rel="stylesheet"
    ></link>
  </>);
```

[chrome://net-export/](http://chrome://net-export/) doesn't show a request for the css file

According to the [timing explanation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation) the possible causes are:

> There are higher priority requests.

But this is the only request

> There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.

Would this apply? I don't make 6 requests to `chrome-extension://` though

> The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache

I don't see why this would happen every time.

Is there any way to check the cause for this?

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome. You can test it in Chrome Canary and a much older Chromium build (a portable or those provided by the [bisect-builds](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) script).

Comment: I still get "Stalled" delay in Canary. I updated the question as to the circumstances of where I'm loading the css in, might that be related?

Comment: Try removing the preload element.

Comment: Still invokes stall time